# Shopify : Open an Iframe when choosing a carrier?

Tags: iframe, shopify

I need to do a Shopify App which requires that when a client choose a shipping carrier, an iframe (or new window) opens up and load an external page. In the Shopify doc I can't find anything about this exactly.

Is it possible to open an iframe or a tab when a client choose a shipping carrier? Maybe with the [CarrierService API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice) ? It seems all it allows is to return supplemental Carrier Rates. Or maybe hook an event after the rate is chosen by the client could do the thing?

Edit: See also this Reddit thread which is pretty the same problem : [Is there any way to open a page when choosing a carrier?](https://www.reddit.com/r/shopify/comments/7mv3tq/app_is_there_any_way_to_open_a_page_when_choosing/)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. You cannot do this. If by choosing a carrier you really mean "when a customer selects a shipping rate option", you cannot trigger code to run in checkout based on that.